# jQuery and getElementById cannot access loaded DOM element (div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, getelementbyid

neither jQuery commands nor getElementById seem to be able to get hold of my DOM items.

part of my script looks like this:

```
var box_size = $("#testbox").height();      
var c = document.getElementById("s1"); 
console.log(c);  // returns null
console.log(box_size); // returns null
console.log($(window).height()); // returns the correct number

c.width = box_size + $(window).height(); // cannot set width of null
```

the excerpt of my DOM tree basically looks like this

```
<div class="wrap" id="mainwrap">
  <div class="row relef">
    <div class="box relef" id="testbox"><canvas id="s1"></canvas></div>
    <div class="box relef"><canvas id="s2"></canvas></div>
    <div class="box relef"><canvas id="s3"></canvas></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrapped my main JS code like this:

```
$(function() {
// my entire js code is wrapped in this
});
```

I think the DOM tree should be loaded by the time my JS gets executed. The elements are hidden using .hide(), but I never deleted them from the DOM tree or similar. The boxes have a set width and height which I can see graphically, as I set their background to red. The size is approximately 80 x 80 px. I checked my HTML code via W3CSchools and there is no error.

Do you have any idea of how the error could have come about?

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'c.width = box_size + $(window).height() * 0.04')
```

EDIT:

```
console.log(document.readyState); // returns "complete"
```

I used it directly before the declaration of box_size

Comment: just copied your code into jsfiddle, and it works! http://jsfiddle.net/me7xd86h/
wrap your entire js inside $(document).ready() to ensure, that the dom is loaded! jsfiddle does that automatically, thats why it's not needed there

Comment: When do you use this code? Is it after the document has been loaded for sure? (like in an onload function)

Comment: When you call JS, the elements exists?

Comment: The only two ways this could happen is if you actually aren't executing your code after the DOM has been loaded, or, the HTML is not present on the same page as the code.

Comment: @errand OP is supposedly using `$(function() { });`

Comment: Are you using correct browser version which supports `<canvas />`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @errand It works in isolation for me, too. But not in my original code. Weird. Markai I am executing the code after a button has been clicked. NicoSantangelo The code is definitely on the same page as I only have 1 HTML page. Mihir I am also using Safari 8 which supports canvas